# Aesthetic pleasure hormone or neurotransmitter

Tags: neuro-transmitters, aesthetics

When a human watched a beautiful painting, a beautiful animation, sees a beautiful nature scene what hormone or neurotransmitter is produced in the organism that he feels the aesthetic pleasure?

Also is it the same chemical as when we hear a beautiful music?

If there are many like for example dopamine, oxytocin and endorphin then which one is the main responsible for the pleasure?

Answer (score 2):

μ-opioid receptors (MOR) have been demonstrated to be involved in our perception of beautiful faces (https://www.medicaldaily.com/seeing-pretty-faces-rewards-brain-perceiving-beauty-all-chemical-reaction-269074).

Here’s [one study](https://doi.org/10.1038/nn.2726) that demonstrates an uptick in dopamine upon listening to music: https://www.bbc.com/news/health-12135590